# How to pronounce `щ`?

Tags: фонетика

I've heard `щ` to be pronounced in Ukrainian exactly like it pronounced in modern standard Russian (as a single phoneme) or like /ʃt͡ʃ/ (shch) - this screenshot is some kind of evidence that it also can be pronounced like /ʃt/

[image]

My question would be - is there a single acceptable form of pronouncing `щ`. If yes, which one? If no - how acceptable are alternatives (like acceptable in colloquial speech, not acceptable at all etc.)

Comment: FYI: Метростанция it's in Bulgarian: https://goo.gl/y2UqJQ

Comment: @ovnia well, what can I say, that means google ukrainian localization suck.

Comment: true. that's just FYI. I've already contributed the right transcription btw :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a commercial software can't serve an evidence of pronunciation.
Especially, if it is about toponyms, which are usually *transliterated*, not *transcribed* ([see the difference between the two](http://www.clickthai-online.com/basics/transcript.html)).

In Standard Ukrainian, `«щ»` is pronounced as a *consonant cluster*, unlike the standard Russian:

- UA: `[ʃ t͡ʃ]`
- RU: `[ɕː]`

In Eastern Ukraine, where many people speak [*surzhyk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk) sociolect, if it easy to hear the `[ɕː]` instead. Assuming the number of speakers, someone may consider it a dialect already.

More phonetic differences are listed [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2581/60).

And no, `«щ»` is not the same thing as `«шт»` `[ʃt]` (however, there is some historic relation). There's even a pair of words to see the difference:

- *щука* — *a pike fish*
- *штука* — *a thing*

As usual, adding dialectal words/pronunciation may add some emotional flavor to one's speech. It can be a double-edged weapon however, so a language learner should probably strive to keep the Standard language unless they master the language well enough.

Comment: I suggest adding information about "ш" that can be prounounced similar to Russian "щ" before "і". And there are words that differ only by this: "пишіть"/"пищіть"; "гуляші"/"гулящі" (though here stress is different).
Also maybe it's a good idea to reference at least English wiki? "The letter щ represents two consonants [ʃt͡ʃ]." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_language

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://youtu.be/dUrx793sn2I?t=1h30m39s) you can listen to probably a perfect pronunciation by Mykola Pohribnyi.

Words in "repeat after me" section:

> горщок
>
> гуща
>
> дещо
>
> дощ
>
> дощечка
>
> ліщина
>
> лящати
>
> нащадки
>
> піщаний
>
> прищ
>
> прощатися
>
> пуща
>
> товща
>
> урочище
>
> хрущ
>
> щавель
>
> щастя
>
> щедрий
>
> щирий
>
> що
>
> щоб
>
> щука
>
> щур
>
> ящик

Answer (score 2):

*Not answer, but just additional information about letter **щ** in variation writing.*

As we already know, the letter can sound like:

- **ʃt** in South Slovs language and is writed as **шт**, but only Bulgars has as 1 letter;
- **ʃ-tʃ** in North, exept Muscowian, and is writed as **шч**, but only Ukrainian has as 1 letter; but some Ukrainian [old spellings](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8_XIX_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F) <sup>*ukr*</sup> also had **щ** as **шч** or **сч** which still is used in Muscowian; one of spellings and known as [drahomaniwka](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drahomanivka) is on 20 ₴, look at image bellow.
- **ɕ**(:) in Muscowian.

It’s a very strange letter, which *no one* need, even for Muscowian:

- stop a [rule](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) <sup>*msc*</sup> about to write **жы**, **шы** as **жи**, **ши**: *шына*, *шит*, *ши*, *шастать*, *шявель*…;
- write **сч** as **ш**ь: *шястье*.

---

*Не відповідь, а просто додаткові відомості про **щ** в способах написаннях.*

Як вже знаємо, буква звучить як:

- **ʃt** в південих слов’янах і пишуть **шт**, окрім болґарів, де 1 буква;
- **ʃ-tʃ** в північних, окрім московської, і пишуть **шч**, лиш українська має як 1 букву; але деякі українські [старі правописи](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8_XIX_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F) також мали **щ** як **шч** or **сч**, котрого московська досі вживає; один з таких правописів, знаний як [драгоманівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), надрукований на 20 ₴;
- **ɕ**(:) in Muscowian.

Вельми дивна буква, котрої *ніхто* не потрeбує, навіть московська:

- відмінити [правило](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) <sup>*мск*</sup> про напису **жы**, **шы** як **жи**, **ши**: *шына*, *шит*, *ши*, *шастать*, *шявель*…;
- писати **сч** відповідно **ш**ь: *шястье*.

---

[image: 20 ₴]

> *Земле, моја всеплодьучаја мати!
>
>   Сили, **шч**о в твојіј движель глубині,
>
>   Крапльу, **шч**об в боју сміліјше стојати,
>
>   дај i міні!*

Comment: Wtf is Muscowian?

Comment: @shabunc language of origin name of a state which is on North of Eurasia and where Moscow is a capital.

Comment: it's called Russian in English and it's utterly stupid to call it anything else.