# Як вимовляти проєкт?

Tags: фонетика

Отже, **[проєкт](https://blog.correctarium.com/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-e88e4f6d9926)** (і похідні від нього) ми тепер пишемо тільки через **-є**. Але як його вимовляти? Як звичне **-е**? Чи все ж як **-є**?

Просто хочу запевнитись, а то чи мало що.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Як -є- [-йе-].

Наскільки я розумію, аргументів за зміну -е- [-е-] на -є- [-йе-] два:

1. Для української мови загалом нехарактерні такі сполучення голосних (наприклад, ми вживаємо Україна [украйіна], а не Украіна [украіна]).
2. В інших словах того ж походження ми вживаємо -є- [-йе-], наприклад, суб'єкт [субйект], а не субект [субект], сюр'єкція [с'урйект͡сійа], а не сюрекція [с'урект͡сійа], траєкторія [трайекторійя], а не траекторія [траекторійя].

P. S.: Наскільки це обов'язково (здається, має бути якийсь перехідний період, коли обидва варіанти вважаються правильними), я не знаю.

Comment: *«нехарактерні такі сполучення голосних»* — citation needed. Також варто уточнити, які це — «такі».

Comment: Брехня. Під впливом СРСР вже всі давно можуть використовувати подібні слова, де використовувалося "е" замість "є". Вже давно характерні. Це так само як ф і хв. Відповідь не сучасна, а книжна.
Це зроблено для повернення до попередніх правил, які були до впливу СРСР на мову.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, якщо я зміню «загалом нехаректерні» на «загалом _історично були_ нехарактерні» — це буде краще?

Answer (score 3):

Українська абетка і державний правопис [опирають ся](https://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Lit/Sh/ShashkevychM/Prose/Peredslivlje.html) на „пиши, як чуєш”. Правда, переважно, бо тут є частина хиби, наприклад десь тут згадана *Україна* не є насправді [украйіна], а [украйина] чи [украйі<sup>и</sup>на] <sup>[[1]](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk402/TK_wisnyk402_morhun'uk.htm)[[2]](https://r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8,%20%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(1941).pdf#page=125)</sup>, для звуків [д͡ж] і [д͡з] немаʼ окремих букв, а *щ* [позначає](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2677/585) 2 звуки [шт͡ш]; але напрям такий, де **є**, котрий після голосної, не виняткує, тому [йе].

Звідси [пройе́кт], за [МФА](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82) [pro'jɛkt] <sup>[[3]](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%A4%D0%90_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)</sup>.

Про обовʼязковість про **є**: [правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=126) не дозволяє зьмін пня *єкт*:

> #### § 126. Звук [j]
>
> Звук **[j]** звичайно передаємо відповідно до вимови іншомовного слова буквою й, а в складі звукосполучень **[je]**, **[ji]**, **[ju]**, **[ja]** буквами **є**, **ї**, **ю**, **я**: […] *інʼє́кція*, *проє́кт*, *проє́кція*, *субʼє́кт*, *траєкторія* […].

Сам корінь може зьмінювати ся, як вже зазначено в статї, від першомови (звук і тлум), цєбто від Французької вже *-жект-*.

[Додатковий огляд](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/osnovni-zminy%202019.pdf) від МОН:

> ### 1. БЕЗ ВАРІАНТІВ
>
> **проєкт, проєкція**
>   (так само як *інʼєкція*, *траєкторія*, *обʼєкт* та інші слова з латинським коренем -ject-)

Comment: "пиши, єк чуїш"

Comment: @PaulGor Добре чуйиш!